# after source ~/.zshrc, zsh terminal does not work

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I try to set up react native android development environment

1. `vim ~/.zshrc`
2. paste ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable
3. `source ~/.zshrc`

However, the following error occurred

```
/Users/username/.zshrc:source:26: no such file or directory: /Users/username/.zshrc#
/Users/username/.zshrc:source:26: no such file or directory: /Users/username/.zshrc#
/Users/username/.zshrc:source:26: no such file or directory: /Users/username/.zshrc#
/Users/username/.zshrc:source:51: too many open files: /Users/username/.zshrc
/Users/username/.zshrc:source:75: too many open files: /Users/username/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh
/Users/username/.zshrc:source:108: too many open files: /Users/username/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
/Users/username/.zshrc:source:109: too many open files: /Users/username/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/prefix.sh: line 40: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
/Users/username/.zshrc:source:112: no such file or directory: /nvm.sh
/Users/username/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:source:61: too many open files: /Users/username/.oh-my-zsh/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh
/Users/username/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:source:122: too many open files: /Users/username/.oh-my-zsh/lib/compfix.zsh
compinit:503: cannot duplicate fd 0: too many open files
/Users/username/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh:31: write error: bad file descriptor
[256]    done       bindkey "$3"
```

And then zsh terminal does not work even `node -v`

It terminated immediately in the vscode

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm assuming your platform is Apple Silicon. Your ~/.zshrc is problematic and needs to be fixed. You can open a new shell using `/bin/zsh -f` to ignore ~/.zshrc, and inspect your ~/.zshrc in that environment. (In Terminal.app, uncheck "login" shell, and input this specific path instead) I also find that you put `#` too close to your command. Since `#` can appear in a file name, you need to put space(s) before it to start a comment. With limited information, that's all that I can think of. It would be useful if you could paste related commands around line 26.

Comment: _How can I solve this problem?_ ... As always, with debugging: Put a `set -x` as first statement of your .zshrc, and open a new terminal tab. Observe the debugging output: It will show you all statements which get executed. From this, you will see which command causes the error and then you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using Oh My Zsh given that this was tagged with oh-my-zsh. As the creator of Oh My Zsh, I would encourage you to not append your Android SDK environment variable to `~/.zshrc` but consider enabling the [dotenv plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv) that comes packaged with Oh My Zsh.

then you can define your `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in the parent directory of your project